# Cual es el error del método Lee?

Tags: c++

Hola me podrían ayudar con el método leer de este codigó ???
De ante mano Millones de gracias....
El método escribir me funciona perfectamente, pero no he podido lograr hacer funcionar el método leer, para que me lea lo que escribo.

Todo me funciona menos eso

// Defino librerias y clases que voy a necesitar.

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<string> 
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#include "Empleado.cpp"

#ifndef ADMIEMPLEADO_CPP
#define ADMIEMPLEADO_CPP

using namespace std;
```

// Defino la clase

```
class admEmpleado{
        private:
                string ruta;
                Empleado *empleado;
                int n;
        public: 
                admEmpleado(string ruta)
                {
                    this->ruta=ruta;
                    empleado = new Empleado[100];
                    n=0;
                }
```

// Inicio de métodos set y get

```
                void setRuta(string ruta){
                    this->ruta=ruta;
                }
                string getRuta(){
                    return ruta;
                }
                // ****
                void addEmpleado(Empleado i){
                    empleado[n]=i;
                    n++;
                }
                void setEmpleado(int pos, Empleado i){
                    if(pos >= 0 && pos <n){
                        empleado[pos] = i;
                    }
                }
                void remEmpleado(int pos){
                    if(pos >= 0 & pos < n){
                        Empleado *t=new Empleado[100];
                        int i=0;
                            for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                                if(pos !=i){
                                    t[i]=empleado[i];
                                    i++;
                                }
                            }
                            // Delete Iempresa
                            empleado->~Empleado();
                            empleado=t;
                            n--;
                    }
                }
                Empleado* getEmpleado(){
                    return empleado;
                }

                int getN(){
                    return n;
                }
```

// Destructor 
                    ~admEmpleado(){}

```
                string token(string cadena, string divisor, int pos){
                        if(cadena.size()>0){
                            char oracion[cadena.size()];
                            for(int i=0; i<=cadena.size(); i++){
                                oracion[i]=cadena[i];
                            }
                            char *ptrtoken;
                            int num=1;
                            const char* d=divisor.c_str();
                            ptrtoken = strtok(oracion, d);
                            while(ptrtoken){
                                if(num==pos){
                                    return ptrtoken;
                                }
                                ptrtoken = strtok(NULL, d);
                                num++;
                            }
                            return "";
                        } else {return "";} 
                }
```

// Metodo de escribir, este me funciona perfectamente

```
                void escribir(){
                    ofstream Escribir;
                    Escribir.open(ruta.c_str());
                        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                            Escribir<<empleado[i].getId()<<";"
                                    <<empleado[i].getNombre()<<";"
                                    <<empleado[i].getEdad()<<";"
                                    <<empleado[i].getSexo()<<";"
                                    <<empleado[i].getEstadocivil()<<";"
                                    <<empleado[i].getNacionalidad()<<";"
                                    <<empleado[i].getTelefono()<<";"
                                    <<empleado[i].getCorreo()<<";"
                                    <<empleado[i].getDepto()<<";"
                                    <<empleado[i].getPuesto()<<endl<<endl;
                        }
                        Escribir.close();
                }
```

// ****************** ESTE METODO ES EL QUE ME DA PROBLEMAS

```
                void leer(){
                    fstream Leer;
                    string linea;
                    Empleado = new Empleado[100];
                    n=0;
                    Leer.open(ruta.c_str());
                        if(Leer.is_open()){
                            while(! Leer.eof()){
                                getline(Leer, linea);
                                    if(linea.size()>0){
                                        addEmpleado(Empleado(atoi(token(linea, ";", 1).c_str()),
                                        token(linea, ";", 2),
                                        atoi(token(linea, ";", 3).c_str())
                                        )
                                        );
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                        Leer.close();
                }

                void print(){
                    cout<<"\n\tEmpleados de la Empresa: "<<endl;
                    cout<<"\t======================== \n"<<endl;
                        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                            cout<<"\t\n";
                            empleado[i].print();
                        }
                }
};
#endif
```

Si comento el codigó del metodo de leer la clase me funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Que tal DIWA, bienvenido... cual es el error que te da en este caso??? seria bueno que nos des mas detalles sobre el problema... sube el error si es el caso...

Comment: Que haces con Empleado = new Empleado[100] si no lo usas despues

Comment: Hola Víctor Hugo Tirado, los errores que me tiran son los siguientes:

1. expected unqualified-id before '=' token
2. no matching function for call to Empleado::Empleado (int, std::string, int)
3. candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided

Comment: Hola nuevo, he agregado más lineas de token en el método y he pasado de tener de 10 errores a solo uno.

Ahora el unico error que me tira es:

expected primary-expression before ')' token

Comment: Hola lo he solucionado, el problema estaba en la lineas que agregaba de token, el constructor tenia 10 lineas y en el token yo solo estaba poniendo 3 lineas.